# empty image field in formset not valid

Tags: django

Why form not valid an empty image field... fall into a database empty records

```
@login_required
def add_photo(request, gallery_id):
gallery = get_object_or_404(Gallery, pk=gallery_id)
PhotoFormSet = formset_factory(PhotoUploadForm, extra=1)
formset = PhotoFormSet()
if request.method == "POST":
    formset = PhotoFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.save(commit=False)
                data.galleries = gallery
                data.save()
return render_to_response("add_photo.html", {'formset': formset, 'album_id': gallery_id}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set required=False on the field for the file in your form?

Could we see the forms definition?

Comment: Solved the problem so                                                     
if form.cleaned_data.get("image") is not None: